# How to detect that a SQL Server database was created by attaching a data file or by restore from Enterprise Manager

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Ours is a SQL Server (2008-R2) - Windows Forms based application. We have a backup/restore utility provided with our software which performs some logical checks before restoring a backup to ensure that the backup is functionally valid.

However, our clients often use the SQL Server Enterprise Manager utility to:

1. Restore backups or
2. Attach data files (kept aside before formatting) directly.

This type of action bypasses all our functional checks and allows the user to restore an invalid backup.

We want to detect that a database was restored/attached and may be we will stop the software from loading if such a thing happened. We think that this information (attach/restore) should be available within some table of SQL Server itself but don't know the right location/query.

If any change is required in our software to achieve the above, we are ready to do the same too, e.g. may be we need to store some data at some point of time to make the detection happen, please advise.

So, how can we detect that

1. A database backup was restored using SQL Server Management Utility

   (Note: MSDB.Restorehistory may not be a good option as we have often found this table blank for unknown reasons even after backup was restored and just in case user restores the MSDB from MSDB backup or MSDB template due to a data corruption, may be due to abnormal shutdown of system, then  the RestoreHistory table data is gone)
2. A database was created by attaching a data/log file using SQL Server Management Utility

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Rajarshi

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that we are using SQL Server Express 2008-R2 edition so some suggested features might not be available.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can use SQL Server Audit (Security\Server Audit Specification), and add `Backup-Restore_Group` option to it in order to log all backup and restore in your server.

You can also read audited data with following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('Your Audit File Path',DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

**this feature is in SQL Server 20088 R2 and above version and not exists in SQL Server 2008.**

**Method 2:**

You can use SQL server error log in order to get backup and restore history:

In order to get backup log of your database:

```
EXEC sys.sp_readerrorlog @p1 = 0, -- int
    @p2 = 1, -- int
    @p3 = N'Database backed up. Database: Attach', -- nvarchar(4000)
    @p4 = N'' -- nvarchar(4000)
```

In order to get restore log of your database:

```
EXEC sys.sp_readerrorlog @p1 = 0, -- int
    @p2 = 1, -- int
    @p3 = N'Database was restored: Database: Attach, -- nvarchar(4000)
    @p4 = N'' -- nvarchar(4000)
```

you can use this method on SQL Server Express 2008-R2 edition.

Comment: Thank you so much. Performed a basic backup/restore operation and this method was able to detect. Will test under some more scenarios and revert. What will be the string to detect a database 'Attach' operation?

Comment: @Rajarshi. I edit my answer and add Attach database in sample.

Comment: I cannot find any results for Attach scenario. Will you please verify by detaching > attaching and then running this query.

Comment: @Rajarshi. I used method 2 in order to get backup and restore log and don't use for attach and detach log until now.